# open source netbeans platform projects that I can use?

Tags: netbeans6.8

I've looked at sourceforge and other places for an example netbeans platform project source code but couldn't find any besides the Pain netbeans platform app that comes included in the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you start at the ['NetBeans Plugin Portal'](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/). Many of the plugins have a link to their home page... which often provides access to the source code.